# C++ How to overload a function which gets as parameter an iterator of different templated objects?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++14, overloading

I have two similar generic classes - MyClass1 and MyClass2.
I want the function "func" to iterate over the elements of MyClass1 and/or MyClass1 objects.

but I get the  folowing error:

```
'auto' in return type deduced as 'Group3d<MyClass1<5> >' here but deduced as 'Group2d<MyClass1<5> >' in earlier return statement
        return funcForClass2<T>(start, end);
        ^
```

I can't figure out how to overload this function, since the type is deduced after calling it.

Any advice?

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    list<MyClass1<5>> a = {{0}, {-5}};
    auto res5 = func(a.begin(), a.end());

    list<MyClass2<6>> b = {{0, 3}, {0, -2}};
    auto res6 = func(b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

utils.h:

```
template<typename T>
using deref_iter_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>;

template<class Iterator>
auto func(Iterator start, Iterator end) {
    int dim;

    using T = deref_iter_t<Iterator>;

    dim = (start)->getDim();
    if (dim == 2) { // MyClass1 objects
        return funcForClass1<T>(start, end);
    }
    if (dim == 3) { // MyClass2 objects
        return funcForClass2<T>(start, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. it's not what causes the problem, I just changed the names to post it here and made a mistake doing so.

Comment: but `getDim()` is a `constexpr` function? I mean: return a compile-time known value?

Comment: dim is 2 for MyClass1 objects, and 3 for MyClass2 objects.

Comment: You will want a [mcve], and the thing you're looking for is sfinae or if constexpr

Comment: @PasserBy or a redesign avoiding the entire issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dim()` is constexpr, you can do it with overload resolution. Slightly simplifying the example to show relevant parts:

```
#include <utility>

struct A {
    static constexpr int x = 1;
};

struct B {
    static constexpr int x = 2;
};

int impl(std::integral_constant<int, 1> ) {
    return {};
}

char* impl(std::integral_constant<int, 2> ) {
    return {};
}


template<class T> auto foo(T t) {
    return impl(std::integral_constant<int, T::x>{});
}

int main() {
    auto f1 = foo(A{});
    auto f2 = foo(B{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your functions as

```
template<size_t I> 
auto func(
  const typename list<MyClass1<I>>::iterator& begin, 
  const typename list<MyClass1<I>>::iterator& end)
{ 
// do something
}

template<size_t I> 
auto func(
  const typename list<MyClass2<I>>::iterator& begin, 
  const typename list<MyClass2<I>>::iterator& end)
{
// do something else 
}
```

For your `deref_iter_t`, is seems you could have used `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` instead, anyway no longer used.